# It would look better with a bit more space above icon on tabs

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bountied-tab

If you hover over the featured tab at the top of the main listing, the icon touches the top of the tab.

---

[image: pointing]

---

Comment: Is this spacing nit only on Stack Overflow? If so, I'm tempted to ask that this question be migrated to Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

When I hover over it there is a small amount of whitespace between the tab line and the icon (in Firefox):

[image: Featured Icon]